# How to create a business page in Facebook

Tags: facebook-pages

I have a personal page on Facebook and now want to start a business page. My own name is also the name of the business, as is my website. When I try to create a business page, Facebook says the name is already in use. How can I get round this?

Comment: If the name is already in use (whether this is used by your own account or someone else) then I imagine you are going to have to choose a different name (or variation of).

Answer (score 1):

If I guessed right, You are talking about the page Address not the name.

If you want to create a page in same Address you created before, you will have to change previous page's Address to other, and same time change the business page's Address to the one you wish to add.